# How can i trigger this jquery script to automatically run after a set amount of time (5 seconds maybe)?

Tags: jquery, html, time

I would like this script to automatically run after 5 seconds. Just getting into jquery and did not know how to do this... Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#dropdown').on('click',function(){

        $('.dropdownwrap').slideToggle();


    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand your question, you want to trigger click() event after 5 seconds, you could use following code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $('#dropdown').on('click', function () {

        $('.dropdownwrap').slideToggle();


    }).delay(5000).queue(function () {
        this.click();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want the click handler to only bind after 5 seconds:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var $dropdownwrap = $('.dropdownwrap');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#dropdown').on('click',function(){
          $dropdownwrap.slideToggle();
      });
    }, 5000);

});
```

The main thing to take away is the `setTimeout` method which allows you to execute a function after a certain period of time, in this case 5000ms.

More information on the setTimeout function on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setTimeout()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#dropdown').on('click',function(){
        setTimeout(function(){$('.dropdownwrap').slideToggle();}, 5000)
    });
});
```

The slideToggle() will be called after 5 seconds.